# How to pipe output to another program in C, using read

Tags: c

I'm trying to read information printed by program `A` from program `B`. How can I pass data from `A` to `B` using `read()`?.

code for `A`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i, j;
    char    instruc_list[11][3] = {"sa", "sb", "ss", "pa", "pb",
"ra", "rb", "rr", "rra", "rrb", "rrr"};

    i = 0;
    while (i < 11)
    {
        j = 0;
        while (j < 3)
        {
            printf("%c", instruc_list[i][j]);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
        printf("\n");
    }
    return (0);
}
```

code for `B`

```
int main()
{
    char buf[4];
    while ((read(0,buf, 4)))
    {
        printf("%s", buf);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this two programs, I get the following result.
[image]

Comment: @Dmitri `Mac` and `linux`.

Comment: In program A, you're not writing the null terminators for the 3-letter strings... and in program B, you're not adding a null char after the characters you read (and haven't initialised `buf`, so it might not contain one).  That's why you're getting garbage between the 3-letter strings you read... `printf()` is continuing past the characters you read because it hasn't found a null yet.

Comment: Also note that `read()` can return -1 for error, which would still test as true for your `while` loop.  You should at least check that `read()` returns greater than 0 (rather than just non-zero), if not put in more thorough error handling.

Comment: @Dmitri Thanks, I have added the null terminator and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `popen()` and `pclose()` functions defined in `stdio.h` to pipe output between programs.

Here's an example program of how to print the output of the ls shell command in your program, taken from this [link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html):

```
FILE *fp;
int status;
char path[PATH_MAX];


fp = popen("ls *", "r");
if (fp == NULL)
    /* Handle error */;


while (fgets(path, PATH_MAX, fp) != NULL)
    printf("%s", path);


status = pclose(fp);
if (status == -1) {
    /* Error reported by pclose() */
    ...
} else {
    /* Use macros described under wait() to inspect `status' in order
       to determine success/failure of command executed by popen() */
    ...
}
```

For your case, you'd call `popen("./A", "r");`.

Comment: @Shiva `./A > ./B` will overwrite the *file* `./B` with the output from `./A`.

Comment: Oops, my bad, what a noob mistake.

Comment: @piRSquared By the way, if you don't mind my asking, how have you become proficient with pandas? All I've been doing is shadowing this tag.

Comment: 4 Years ago I took on a project that threw me head long into pandas.  But none of that was as effective as answering questions on SO.  Seriously, go back and read some of my earlier questions and answers.  I've come a long way in a year.  What you're doing is perfect.  Keep it up.

Comment: @piRSquared Thank you. That is reassuring. One last question. Have you had problems with tactical targeted down voting? How have you dealt with it?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yes. It always seems to be new folks or someone you've pissed off. I usually leave a comment politely asking for an explanation so I can improve my answer. I've been surprised by responses. Turns out that Jeff, current maintainer of pandas, has downvoted a few of my answers because he isn't a fan of me providing numpy oriented answers. I respect him, and his opinion. Best I can do is engage in a constructive manner where we both end up happy. Other than that, don't let it get to you. If you need to, send me a link to the answer. Happy to help out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `popen()` to read the output of program A from program B.
Compile the first program:

```
gcc a.c -o a
```

In the program B:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buf[4];
    FILE *fp;

    fp = popen("./a", "r");
    while( !feof(fp)) {
        fscanf(fp, "%s", buf);
        printf("%s\n", buf);
    }
    return 0;
    pclose(fp);
}
```

Now compile and execute the program B:

```
gcc b.c -o b

me@linux:$ ./b
```

The output I got is:

```
sa
sb
ss
pa
pb
ra
rb
rr
rra
rrb
rrr
rrr
```

Answer (score 0):

In program A, you're not writing the null terminators for the 3-letter strings... and in program B, you're not adding a null char after the characters you read (and haven't initialised buf, so it might not contain one). That's why you're getting garbage between the 3-letter strings you read... printf() is continuing past the characters you read because it hasn't found a null yet.

Also note that read() can return -1 for error, which would still test as true for your while loop. You should at least check that read() returns greater than 0 (rather than just non-zero), if not put in more thorough error handling.

So with some changes to address these issues, program B might become:

```
int main()
{
    char buf[4];

    int ret; // ** for the return from read()

    while ((ret = read(0,buf, 4)) > 0) // ** read >0 (no error, and bytes read)
    {
        fwrite(buf, 1, ret, stdout); // ** write the number of chars
                                     //    you read to stdout
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

As for program A, right now it writes 3 characters for both the 2-letter and the 3-letter strings -- which means it includes the null char for the 2-letter strings but not for the 3-letter strings.  With the changes to program B above, you don't need to write the null characters at all... so you could change:

```
    while (j < 3)
```

to:

```
    while (j < 3 && instruc_list[i][j] != 0)
```

to stop when the null character is reached (though it's still inefficient to use a `printf()` call just to write a single `char` -- perhaps `putchar(instruc_list[i][j]);` would be better).  Or, you could just replace that inner `while` loop with:

```
    fputs(instruc_list[i], stdout);
```

...which would then write the string in `instruc_list[i]` up to but not including the null char, and also change `instruc_list[11][3]` to `instruc_list[11][4]` so that it has room for the null char from the 3-letter string literals in the initialiser list.